# Build specific module in multi-module project

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a multi-module project.

I thought I can compile only a single module from that multi module project with this line:

```
mvn -amd -pl "module-name"
```

This does not seem to work, but only builds the specific module. Its dependencies are not compiled yet so it fails.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `mvn -am -pl "module-name"` instead (replace `-amd` with `-am`).

The `-amd` flag tries to build projects that *depend upon* "module-name" whereas `-am` builds projects that "module-name" depends upon.  I feel that the documentation on those flags is a little counter-intuitive, but I'm pretty sure that this will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks ..!! Maven -- The Hell on earth .. :-)